# Why don't JavaScript libraries use error handling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, error-handling, underscore.js

I have looked through underscore.js and backbone.js, both two very popular libraries and noticed that they don't use error handling (try, catch, exception).

What is the reason for this decision?

Comment: Because you have browsers like internet explorer:p You are gonna run into situations where your best try catch won't even work. When IE desides to crash it will.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an underscore or backbone function that you think would be improved by catching exceptions internally?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Underscore or backbone function? What kind terminology is that?

Comment: @Christian, the same thing as `function from the underscore.js or backbone.js libraries`, only lighter.

Comment: Or at least, they don't use it _much_ - a quick count of the current source shows they each throw errors in a handful of places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually when you write quality javascript code you don't really need try/catch. Exceptional logic is handled through if conditions and error handlers instead of catching exceptions at runtime.

Comment: So error handling is mostly for bad code or situations where the developer knows something is getting wrong? Good code doesn't leave space for "missbehaviours" and uses external test libs (like expresso or mocha in node)?

Comment: jQuery/Sizzle uses `try/catch` as a means of defaulting to `querySelectorAll`. NodeJS uses it at times as well.

Comment: I am not sure if this maybe belongs in some extra question but what is with function parameter mapping. Isn't this the source of many issues?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Now that's some optimism! What makes you think that javascript libraries like jQuery are well written (quality javascript code - in your own words)?

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at these libraries does reveal several uses of `throw` and `catch`, so they do use exceptions, albeit sparingly.

Exceptions are useful where extra parameters could make functions cumbersome and unreadable and/or 'normal' preconditions for running the code have been badly broken beyond a predictable error case.

It seems a bit confusing to use the term 'error handling' as if you avoid exceptions but pass back an error value from a function this is still error handling.